# PHP Mysqli select value from data base using local storage value

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get value from local storage and select the value from data base using php but when i do that am getting error:`PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xxx\xx\xxxx_\xxxx\mainmenu.php on line 23` but when i echo the string of php i.e $abc and $abc1 that gives me the value but while selecting error is howing up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var employee_ID =   localStorage.getItem('Userid');
    var CompanyID = localStorage.getItem('CompID');;
</script>
<?php  
    $abc = "<script>document.write(employee_ID)</script>"; 
    $abc1 = "<script>document.write(CompanyID)</script>";  

    $sqlewqeqwweqwe = "SELECT  Type_of_Employement  FROM professional where Employee_ID='$abc', Company_ID='$abc1' ";

    $result123 = $mysqli->query($sqlewqeqwweqwe);

    if ( $result123->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($rowsas2 = $result123->fetch_assoc()) {                   
            echo $rowsas2["Type_of_Employement"] ;          
        }
    }
    else 
    {

    }
?>
```

Comment: what is in line 23 ?

Comment: @rcs `   if ( $result123->num_rows > 0) {`

Comment: what happen to the variable naming `$sqlewqeqwweqwe` and `$abc1` ?

Comment: Don't forget to validate the user submitted data with PHP (for security **NEVER** rely on javascript for validation and use a prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

You having problem in query in where condition

```
 SELECT  Type_of_Employement  FROM professional where Employee_ID='$abc', Company_ID='$abc1'

                                                                        ^^
```

Instead of `,` use `AND` or `OR` according to your condition

And you forget to execute your query

```
$sqlewqeqwweqwe = "SELECT  Type_of_Employement  FROM professional where Employee_ID='$abc' AND  Company_ID='$abc1' ";

        $result123 = $mysqli->query($sqlewqeqwweqwe);
        $result123->execute();// execute your query
```

To check error in query we use

```
if (!$mysqli->query("YOUR QUERY")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: i did used and instead of , but still gives me same errror

Comment: then print $abc and $abc1, check if they are non-empty

Comment: use `$result123->execute();` to execute your query

Comment: oh yes!! @Shaik please do that

Comment: am not sure what is wrong still am not getting any result

Comment: echo your query and check directly into your phpmyadmin and check what it return!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you parse the data after getting value from local storage?

Try this, might be it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var employee_ID =   localStorage.getItem('Userid');
    employee_ID = parseInt(employee_ID);
    var CompanyID = localStorage.getItem('CompID');
    CompanyID = parseInt(CompanyID);
</script>
```

Send the both variable through ajax to your php script.

If it works please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your query with this one:

```
$sqlewqeqwweqwe = "SELECT  `Type_of_Employement`  FROM `professional` where `Employee_ID`='".$abc."' and `Company_ID`='".$abc1."' ";
```

that's it :)

Comment: the error is not showin but no result is also showing